# How to create Custom Navigation Bar like BestBuy App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to make a custom navigation bar as like in the BestBuy App or like shown in the below given screenshot.

[image]

I want this type of Navigation to be always on the top of each and every viewController.

If anyone can tell me the procedure or any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think they are using custom navigation bar...it's simple image:)

Comment: they likely don't.. I agree. my answer is overkill for this .. it is most flexible but aziz's code look better suited for THIS I think. .. though I don't know about the background separators

Answer (score 11, accepted):

write a subclass of UINavigationBar in which you do custom drawing and add subviews as needed.

then tell your navigationController to use that class by initing it using `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolBarClass:`

e.g.

```
@interface MyBar : UINavigationBar
@end

@implementation MyBar 
.... //like any UIView
@end
```

---

```
UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[MyBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
```

instead of `initWithRootViewController`

---

Sample

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.mainViewController = [[FDMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FDMainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    self.mainViewController = [[FDMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FDMainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[UINavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
navi.viewControllers = @[self.mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navi;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: How to tell navigationController to use that class?

Comment: Then how i will set the root controller?

Comment: push it non-animated or set navi.viewControllers = @[rootVC]

Comment: I didn't understood the concept of push it non-animated. Is this the right way of doing it ?

Comment: Not Working !! Navigation Bar is Black!     self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; 

Color is not getting changed !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24109/discussion-between-rajan-balana-and-daij-djan)

Answer (score 4):

navigationBar can take three view, two buttons in each side left and right , also you can add a view for the title,,

```
//this will set a background image to your navigation bar.
[[self.navigationController navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[leftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 30);
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];

UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"add-btn.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doneAct) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

and to add the search bar

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = mySearchbarView;
```

Comment: yes, if you don't need the separators for example... though those could be in background image.. this works for most cases

Comment: sure, but then the button won't be highlighted on touch, your answer is better to go with.