# How to remove navigation subview when view disapper?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, customization

I am using custom navigation view for navigation bar.

```
CustomNavigation *navigation = [[CustomNavigation alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomNavigation" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navigation.view];
```

This is my code for custom navigation to addsubview for navigation. I am using in viewwillapper. Because it's show and hide image and button based from popviewcontroller.

Here my problem is I need to dealloc this customnavigation view but I am already tried in view disappear it won't work? :( (I am using find that issue by "debug view hierarchy" in Hide or show debug area )

Am I using correct way for custom navigation bar or else give me correct way to create customized navigation bar?

If this is correct way to create customized navigation bar then how to dealloc this custom navigation view when view disapper?

I am new bee for xcode so give some little more explanation **maybe** I am struggles to understand. :(

[image: Sample APP navigation only one at home screen also pop from another view]

Sample APP navigation only one at home screen also pop from another view

[image: Sample APP second view]

Sample APP at second view

[image: My app at home screen]

My app at home screen

[image: After few view my home screen navigation]

After few view my home screen navigation

Check all screens you will understand what I want.
I want to dealloc all navigation bar allocation form manually.

Screen shot's from "debug view hierarchy" in Hide or show debug area - XCODE.

Comment: Have you seen `- (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass`?

Comment: No. What I do with that..??

Comment: Check out this StackOverflow post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747665/how-to-create-custom-navigation-bar-like-bestbuy-app

Comment: What i understand form that link- How to create navigation bar. But here in my case already created custom navigation add subview for uinavigation. I need to dealloc that memory. If I push to 1VC to 2VC and then popout form 2VC. Now I am check "debug view hierarchy" in Hide or show debug area it's show 3 navigation bar.

Comment: Show the code you're using to add the subviews, where is it?

Comment: @Wain i am already mention in question "viewwillapper". Same code I am using in app. Under that hide and show menu button navigation title like that no extra code in "viewwillapper".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me :)

Add a tag for that view each time when I use add subview code before

```
for(UIView *view in [self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews])
    {
        if(view.tag == 1000 && [view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        {
            navigation = nil;
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

If it's not perfect answer then show the correct one. Advance thanks.